# portugese characters in DBsqlite and python parsing not recognised

Tags: python, sqlite, character-encoding, python-2.x

I got a database in DBsqlite.in this DBsqlite database I have have a records containing portugese text like "Hiper-radiação simétrica periocular bem delimitada, homogênea."

and the characters like ç ã é ê don't parse right in my python script.

While normal english text is doing it perfectly.

In my terminal window (I use a mac) the

I know it has something do to with the encoding. but the code still doesn't recognise portugese.

my sample code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

#open a database connection to the database translateDB.sqlite
conn = sqlite3.connect('translateDB.sqlite')

#prepare a cursor object using cursus() method
cursor = conn.cursor()

#test input
# this doesn't work
text = ('Hiper-radiação simétrica periocular bem delimitada,   homogênea')

# this does work in english
#text = ('Well delimited, homogeneous symmetric periocular hyper-    radiation.')

# Execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM translate WHERE L2_portugese=?', (text,))

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method and display it.
print cursor.fetchone()

# Disconnect from server
conn.close()
```

any tips & tricks are greatly appreciated. Ron

Comment: In my terminal window (I use a mac) the sql statements are working fine in portugese and english.

Comment: Show the code that writes the data to the database.

Comment: I copied the text into database manually.

Comment: at this moment is is just 7 lines of portugese in which I need to search and find the english translation. but this will grow significantly in a few weeks.

Comment: Your manual copying used a wrong encoding.

Comment: thanks CL, do you have a way to do this in a correct way?

Comment: I cannot tell you what exactly you did wrong when you keep it a secret.

Comment: CREATE TABLE translate (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
 Line INTEGER, 
 L1_portugees TEXT, 
 L3_engels TEXT,
 L2_nederlands TEXT
)

Comment: and I copied manually the L1_portugees, L3_engels and L2_nederlands records

Comment: with copied I mean filled with data. at this moment it is just 7 lines so very easy to manually type them into the database. but this will grow in a few weeks.

Comment: L1_portugees contains a sentence in portugese; L3_engels contains the translation of the portugese sentence in english and L2_nederlands contains the translation of the portguese sentence in dutch. and when I do an select statement to search in the portugese record I want to get the translated sentences in english and dutch.

Comment: my SELECT * FROM translate WHERE L2_portugese=?', (text,) statement goed wrong as it doesn't recognise the characters like ç ã é ê in portugese.

Comment: Which tool did you use to execute the INSERT statements?

Comment: I just went into my DB browser for SGLite - went to browse data and into the translate table. here I see my 5 records id, Line, L1_portugees, L3_engels,l2_nederlands. I pressed new record and just typed in the sentences.